# Save data to different model inside a controller

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a CakePHP controller named ProjectsController (and it's model named Project) and a Settings model.
Inside the ProjectsController, there is a settings function, where inside it I need to save data into the database using the Settings model. The function is the following:

```
public function settings($pid = null) {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->loadModel('Settings');
            $this->request->data['Project']['id'] = $pid;
            if($this->Settings->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Settings successfully set.'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'view', $pid));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong! Please try again.'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'settings', $pid));
            }
        }
    }
```

But it always fails and returns Something went wrong! 
I have also to say that the Settings model has a hasOne relationship with Projects

```
public $hasOne = 'Project';
```

This is my first time trying to achieve something like this so please help me and tell me what am I doing wrong here,why this is not working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: first of all the model you have t load is `Setting` (singular) and not `Settings`. Then we need to know if the data is in the right form so please post a print_r of your `$this->request->data`

Comment: print_r($this->request->data) resulted in those: Array ( [Project] => Array ( [tracker] => Array ( [0] => true ) [adminOnly] => Array ( [0] => false ) ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, a `save()` call, will save only the model's data. a `saveAll()` call will save any related (flat, first level) model's data.

You can also try `$this->Model->associatedModel->save()`

Comment: omg,yes,there were validation errors! I fixed my $validate and now everything works smoothly! Thank you!